# MySQL INSERT [...] SET not working

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-insert

So what's wrong with this query:

```
INSERT `ttf` SET `weight_id` = 4  WHERE `weight_id` = 4
```

Syntax reference from the official MySQL manual:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

My query returns an error:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `weight_id` = 4' at line 1
```

Yes, I have MySQL server v.5.6, and I know about the normally used INSERT  [...] VALUES(...) syntax, but I want to use the SET syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) syntax

```
UPDATE `ttf` SET `weight_id` = 4  WHERE `weight_id` = 4
```

As you correctly said `INSERT` syntax doesn't support `WHERE` since it is inserting a new row and not updating an old one wich would require to know which row to update.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found it. 
Insert doesn't support WHERE.

The error message could've been helpful!